# Bluez 5.37 : Unable to register GATT service with handle

Tags: bluez

Using Bluez 5.37 bluetoothd. I compile my with flag --disable-systemd.

Using bluetoothctl to connect to my local bluetooth server.
After connecting it does not show any services on dbus.

I can see the following error in bluetoothd log:

```
bluetoothd[22098]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x0001, end: 0x0004, uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
bluetoothd[22098]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x0010, end: 0x0015, uuid: 00001827-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
bluetoothd[22098]: src/device.c:gatt_client_ready_cb() status: success, error: 10
bluetoothd[22098]: src/device.c:device_svc_resolved() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_BA_8F err 0
bluetoothd[22098]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_ready() GATT client ready
bluetoothd[22098]: src/gatt-client.c:create_services() Exporting objects for GATT services: XX:XX:XX:XX:BA:8F
bluetoothd[22098]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0001 for device XX:XX:XX:XX:BA:8F
bluetoothd[22098]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0010 for device XX:XX:XX:XX:BA:8F
```

On dbus I cannot see any service or characteristics populated. I need to use bluez 5.37, is there any fix for this?

Note: I have masked bd address as XX:XX:XX:XX:BA:8F

Answer (score 0):

This was basically unable to register the objects on dbus interface.

Resolved this by running bluetoothd in "experimental" mode using "E" flag.
like:
./bluetoothd -ndE